# Multiple <input type="radio" /> with the same name,how to know which is checked from PHP?

Tags: php, radio-button

```
...
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" />
..
```

Supposed it's submited with method="POST".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a value to your input radio.

```
<input type="radio" value="somevalue" name="something">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the value of the item in the response tag - give each of your radio buttons in the group gets a value.

Then use the name of your radio button to access the request object for that name.  The value indicates which is checked.